# NodeJS HTTP Header info for redirects

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, httpresponse, http-response-codes

say a user navigates to a URL that returns a `301` in the header. In addition to that, they are redirected 2-3 times. Is it possible to grab each url within the redirect chain and output it? Instead of just doing `response.headers.location`

Comment: You can disable automatic redirect handling and instead perform redirects yourself, and log each url along the way.

Comment: How would I go about disabling it?

Comment: I don't believe the redirect behavior of the `http` module is documented. I would assume Node.js actually doesn't handle redirects automatically. The infamous [request](https://github.com/request/request) library lists automatic redirect handling as one of its features.

Comment: If you're just trying to debug one specific situation, you can use a network trace (from a tool like WireShark) to watch the various 301 redirects go by.